# How to create functionality of Convert to Template in custom contrls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created Custom control for Email where i have textbox and expression validator.and I have added the class library projects dll to toolbox.

when I drag and drop then my control is working also I have made that control as templated control.If I drag and drop the control and write my own markup then also its working but instead of writing markup i want that when I go to design of aspx page and select my control then in smart tag I should get option for convert to template and when i click on that by default markup which i have given in control should be render.Can anyone help me to achieve this.

My code for template is

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomControl
{

[ParseChildren(ChildrenAsProperties = true)]
[ValidationPropertyAttribute("Text")]
public class Email : CompositeControl, INamingContainer
{


    /// <summary>
    /// declaration of variable of type ITemplate
    /// </summary>
    private ITemplate layoutTemplate;
    private Control myLayoutTemplateContainer;



    /// <summary>
    /// Property which is used as tag for specify the markup in control
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true),
    DefaultValue(null),
    Description("The layout template."),
    TemplateContainer(typeof(EmailTemplateContainer)),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate LayoutTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return layoutTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            layoutTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This textbox is used for enter emailid
    /// </summary>
    private TextBox emailTextbox;


    /// <summary>
    /// Regular expression validator
    /// </summary>
    private RegularExpressionValidator emailValidationExpression;

    /// <summary>
    /// This property contains maxlength of textbox
    /// </summary>
    private int maxLength;

    public int MaxLength
    {
        get
        {
            return maxLength;
        }
        set
        {
            maxLength = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This property contains Validation group for textbox control
    /// </summary>
    private string validationGroup;

    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return validationGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            validationGroup = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Control container for Layout template
    /// </summary>
    public Control MyLayoutTemplateContainer
    {
        get
        {
            return myLayoutTemplateContainer;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // If markup for control is given then if block will execute otherwise else block will execute which is default
        if (LayoutTemplate != null)
        {
            myLayoutTemplateContainer = new EmailTemplateContainer(this);
            LayoutTemplate.InstantiateIn(myLayoutTemplateContainer);
            Controls.Add(myLayoutTemplateContainer);
        }
        else
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// This is default markup for control if markup to the control is not given then this block will execute
            /// </summary>
            //Assigning properties to textbox
            this.emailTextbox = new TextBox();
            this.emailTextbox.ID = "EmailTextbox";
            emailTextbox.MaxLength = this.MaxLength;
            this.Controls.Add(emailTextbox);

            // Email regular expression validators properties
            this.emailValidationExpression = new           RegularExpressionValidator();
            emailValidationExpression.ValidationGroup =     this.ValidationGroup;
            emailValidationExpression.ControlToValidate = emailTextbox.ID;
            emailValidationExpression.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            emailValidationExpression.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "red");
            emailValidationExpression.ValidationExpression = Constant.EMAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION;
            emailValidationExpression.ErrorMessage = Resource.WrongEmailMessage;
            this.Controls.Add(emailValidationExpression);
        }
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (emailTextbox != null)
        {
            emailTextbox.RenderControl(writer);
            emailValidationExpression.RenderControl(writer);

        }

        if (myLayoutTemplateContainer != null)
        {
            myLayoutTemplateContainer.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}


public class EmailTemplateContainer : Control, INamingContainer
{
    private Email parent;

    public EmailTemplateContainer(Email parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return parent.ValidationGroup;
        }
    }

    public int MaxLength
    {
        get
        {
            return parent.MaxLength;
        }
    }
}
```

}